# Need pointers for Low Quality Posts Review

Tags: support, faq, answer-quality, flagging, question-quality

I have recently got access to *Low Quality Posts Review*. I tried to look into Meta for related questions or some guidelines on the site for what action to make when and what to look for in posts.
However I am not able to get pointers.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/182734 or better this one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029

Answer (score 6):

The guidelines for questions, I reckon, are pretty straightforward. You'll **close** if a question deserves closure, vote **looks OK** if the flag isn't justified and **skip** if you're unsure.

You have four options for answers: **Looks OK**, **Edit**, **Recommend deletion**, **Skip**. Let's see what answers you have to recommend to be deleted first; as its the most straightforward.

### Recommend Deletion:

You can recommend that an answer be deleted. If you're a [trusted user](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), you can directly vote to delete an answer with a score of -1 or lower. Adding a comment is optional, but

You shouldn't comment on these: (It doesn't really make sense)

- Spam:

  > then I went through but she said you can't win and then I totally hear cookies relevant to poisonous gorillas
  >
  > - Great dangling icebergs
  > - stock market pranksters
  > - ghost virus eat your zombie
  >
  > but [Testo X Factor Xplode](http://example.com) useful muscle weight long night laughing but I know cramped streets eat bananas. http://example.com
- Gibberish:

  > asdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjkl

You should comment on these:

- VLQ answers: (Very Low Quality posts)

  > I think the movie is called TERMINATOR 9: AGE OF ULTRON.

  With

  > This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

  An additional "you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)." will be there if the user has less than 50 reputation.
- A new question:

  > OkAY now i so didn't understund theez answers lol. what does Nemo say in *Elysium*?

  With

  > If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.
- A thanks post:

  > Thank you I love you ur answer changed my life soooo much!

  With

  > Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.
- A [link-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) answer:

  > Yo dawg you should totally take a look at [this](http://this). It haz your answer.

  With

  > Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Hope I didn't miss one since I did this by memory. Anyways, here are some pro tips:

- **Review carefully**: You're now bearing a more important responsibility. Any action you take will contribute to or degrade site's quality:

  1. I always open a link to the question. Unfortunately, sometimes the context can be hard to understand from the answer itself. Open a link to the post, and study the whole thread if it's not obvious what you should do.
  2. Don't be afraid of clicking **skip**. One big problem SE is tackling with is people who don't review carefully ([Robo-reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223947/can-we-have-a-system-to-submit-potential-robo-reviewers-for-moderators-attention), so they're called). If you choose the wrong course of action, you'll be no different from them.
- **Judge the content, not the author**: [*Dura lex sed lex*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dura_lex,_sed_lex). If a high-rep user doesn't bother to write an answer that meets the quality standards of the site, they should be treated the same way everyone else is being treated.
- **Don't vote to delete technically wrong answers!**: A question or an answer can be pretty bad, but still can be on-topic or "qualifying" as an answer. Do not delete answers because they're misleading or wrong. Downvotes are for that.
- Last but not the least, it doesn't make sense to choose to comment when someone else already has done. Only one comment is enough.

Comment: Very nice and exhaustive summary!

Comment: And I didn't even say when you should edit, skip or press looks OK. I think those would be vivid enough when this is.

Comment: Indeed, but one might also say it might be general knowledge not necessarily related to the low quality queue in particular that edits, if possible, are to be preferred over downvotes. But sure, one could go on for pages. There's also the whole intricacy of when is an answer not an answer and what to do with perfectly correct one-liners without explanation. But we also have some interesting existing meta discsussions on some of those aspect lying a round that I might dig up in the near future. But for a start, this is definitely a great tutorial for the VLQ queue.

Comment: Tom I wouldn't want to get to the more complicated details in a post that is requesting for a tutorial. Sure, they'll understand it's not really easy to judge every time and following what's written here won't help at times.

Comment: Sure, I didn't want to imply you should. I only agreed that there is definitely more to be said. Afterall, it doesn't have to be the only answer and a little more detail or further pointers in an additional answer by someone else might not hurt.